# Ranking numpy arrays to return arrays of ranks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, ranking

I have a 3-dimensional NumPy array representing n matrices of dimensions x,x. For example with n=3 and x=2, an example would be:

```
matrices = np.array([[[2,8],[1,7]],[[3,1],[5,4]],[[9,6],[2,3]]]

matrices
array([[[2, 8],
        [1, 7]],

       [[3, 1],
        [5, 4]],

       [[9, 6],
        [2, 3]]])
```

I want to create a new array of identical shape, but with values being the ranking of these matrices for each element (i.e. ranking along axis 0). Results would be as follows:

```
array([[[1, 3],
        [1, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 2]],

       [[3, 2],
        [2, 1]]])
```

I can see how to sort (np.argsort(matrices, axis=0)), but can't find an easy way to return ranking. Matrix dimensions x could be high so fast run time would be important. Also the distribution of python used does not include scipy.

I have found that the following works:

```
def rank_stations(input):
    output = [0] * (np.size(input))
    for i, x in enumerate(sorted(range(len(input)), reverse=True, key=lambda y: input[y])):
        output[x] = i+1
    return output

results = np.apply_along_axis(rank_stations, 0, matrices)
```

With five matrices of dimension 980 x 980, this runs in about 6 seconds compared with 20 sec with the modelling software calculations so a reasonable improvement. The sorting algorithm runs in a fraction of a second though so is there a way to get similar run times with ranking?

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.apply_along_axis` with `scipy.stats.rankdata`:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, 0, matrices)
```

Or using `np.argsort` twice:

```
f = lambda x: x.argsort().argsort()
np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, matrices) + 1
```

Output:

```
array([[[1., 3.],
        [1., 3.]],

       [[2., 1.],
        [3., 2.]],

       [[3., 2.],
        [2., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However the distribution of python I use comes with a specific modelling software and does not include scipy. I will try to add but it's not ideal as other users would need to do the same. Any other way not involving scipy?